# unable to download all songs from server

Tags: iphone

in my app i am having a button called download all clicking on which i have to download all songs present on my server. i am able to download one song at a time.
Below is my code:

NetworkManager *manager = [[NetworkManager alloc] init];

```
NSString *Mp3filePath = [manager GetFile:SongUrl];



NSLog(@"aaaaa");


SongUrl= [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"my URL"];

NSLog(@"aaaaa");



NSLog(@"songurl--%@",SongUrl);
```

Comment: What is your question!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

steps to consider:

1. Download a list of songs
2. Compose this list of songs into URLs (if they aren't already)
3. Iterate over the list of songs, downloading them one by one.
4. If process is interrupted (network lost or user cancel), record what you have downloaded, so you can resume again.

Comment: Hey Alex i understand your point but can u help me with code i am trying to do this with storing the URLs in an array and then using a for loop but not getting to the point.......

Comment: Please provide the code for getting the URLs, and running the for loop.  get the for loop to print the urls.

Comment: please provide a reference / documentation / link for the NetworkManager class.